# Evento OnClick Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo dos eventos (`OnClick y Focusout`). A la hora de hacer `click` en un `input` el `focusout` esta esperando para que este `input` pierda el foco y salte este mismo evento, pero si hago `click` en otro elemento salta primero el `focusout`, y después de esto tengo que volver a dar `click` en el elemento para que coja el evento `onclick`, hay alguna manera de que capturar los dos eventos a la vez? Un saludo.

Comment: Por favor incluye el código de lo que has intentado hacer.

Comment: No puedo poner codigo, es un fallo de otro compañero que estoy intentando solucionar. Solo queria saber si se puede capturar el evento de `onclick` despues de que se haga el `focusout`.

Comment: No es necesario que pongas el código entero, basta con un ejemplo que muestre el escenario

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los eventos de javascript se pueden llamar en 2 puntos distintos `Capturing` y `Bubbling`

[image: Evento js]

Más info: [#event-flow](https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-flow)

Puedes llegar a llamar los 2 métodos javascript capturando el `focusout` con `useCapture` `true` y el `onclick` con `useCapture` `false`

Desde jQuery siempre estás usando `useCapture` `false` [Mas info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24585698/capturing-and-bubbling-using-jquery)

Para poder realizar ambas acciones debes de añadir el listener usando javascript, donde `window` és el elemento que tendrá el listener deseado.

```
window.addEventListener('click',click(),false);
window.addEventListener('focusout',focusOut(),true);
```

[Documentación addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)

Comment: Funciona compañero! Gracias por tu ayuda, llevaba buscando esto mucho tiempo!!!